# How to get clvmd running on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, lvm, cluster

I'd like to get `clvmd` running on Ubuntu 15.10 which currently fails and failed (I'm summarizing resolved issues as well) due to

- failure of start of service `clvm` because of missing ~`/etc/init/functions` (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1551980 for details)
- failure of start of service `clvm` due to missing `cman_tool` binary, reported as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1551433
- absense of documentation of important configuration files (e.g. `/etc/cluster/cluster.conf`)
- building git.fedorahosted.org/git/cluster.git (with corosync 1.x https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-cluster/2016-March/msg00000.htmlwhich might not be the only possible combination, but that hard to tell without any usable build instructions) fails with `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-31/include/linux/types.h:14:26: error: conflicting types for`fs_set'` which also occurs with 4.2.0, 4.2.5 and 4.3.3

There seems to be no example for a `cluster.conf` in the search engine indexed world. How can the permanent failure of a service make it into a stable release?